# ActionBar and sliding out menu in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-sliding

I just want to create an action bar as foursquare app. [image]

and i want to show a slide out menu when the home button pressed just like the image shown.
[image]

I am able to create the custom action bar but not like the first image. Please provide any tutorial which will help to create the Action bar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the version included in the Google Android SDK (instead of an 3rd party lib.)

Read about [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

[SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is a great and easy-to-use library for this.

edit: Sorry, thought the question was only about the slide-in menu. 
For actionbar, your best library will be [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)