# What is the new slide-menu that apps like 4sq and G+ are using recently?

Tags: android, google-plus, foursquare, slidingmenu

well, I am working with an slide-menu library a couple of months ago (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), but I'm having trouble working with it since I'm using a Map fragment and I have this error: [How to remove black cover on top of sliding menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173075/how-to-remove-black-cover-on-top-of-sliding-menu)

I have worked with some workarounds about how to "solve" this issue, but anyways, in some phones doesn't look that fine. So I was wondering about changing slide-menu library, and then I saw 4sq and G+ changing theirs. About a month ago, for example, G+ used to look like this: [How did Google manage to do this? Slide ActionBar in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234375/how-did-google-manage-to-do-this-slide-actionbar-in-android-application)
And 4sq like this: [ActionBar and sliding out menu in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129985/actionbar-and-sliding-out-menu-in-android), but now they changed (to the same slide menu library I guess) and look like this:

[image]

You can see here that 4sq app changed the menu most likely because they suffered same issue with the map fragment.

[image]

As you can see, now slide menu goes OVER the view, and it has 3 horizontal tiny bars that hints the user to tap on it in order to discover a menu. Those bars shrink and expand when expanding/colapsing the menu.

[image]

I remember once I saw someone here in stackoverflow referencing this library, It's just I can't remember the name of the library neither the question I read it from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the new [`DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) class in the support library. There's an entire page devoted to setting it up [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

To get more informations about practices, design or navigation, check this [page](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Comment: That is the one, thanks @karakuri. I guess since it's included in android.support.v4 I can make it work from 2.3.3 (API 10) and above, right?

Comment: You do need an `ActionBar` for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. It may be possible to use with ActionBarSherlock, but I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Well, following [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/) seems to be possible. Now it comes to me, how it is possible to have rigth and left side navigation drawers? just like G+ images here. And even further, is it possible to have more than one each side? triggered by different buttons?

Comment: You can add another child view to the DrawerLayout with a different `layout_gravity`. I've managed to have two drawers at the same time, one with `android:layout_gravity="start"`and `android:layout_gravity="end"`